# HTML2PDF not showing the left border of <td>

Tags: php, html, css, html2pdf

I have a table of 5 columns that is generated using php. I want only the cells containing text to have a border but the length of the columns may differ. The following works fine in a browser but when using `HTML2PDF` I lose the left border of some cells as shown below.

**numberOfRowsInTable** will hold the total size of the table

**$arrayCol*[ ]** holds the values for each cell (one array for each column)

**CSS**

```
table {
border-collapse: collapse;    
}

.leftCell
{
border: 1px solid black;
}

.noborder
{
border: 0px;
}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$numberOfRowsInTable = 0;

if ($numberOfRowsInCol1> $numberOfRowsInTable )
{$numberOfRowsInTable = $numberOfRowsInCol1;}

if ($numberOfRowsInCol2> $numberOfRowsInTable)
{$numberOfRowsInTable = $numberOfRowsInCol2;}

.... etc from 1 to 5

if ($numberOfRowsInCol5> $numberOfRowsInTable )
{$numberOfRowsInTable = $numberOfRowsInCol5;}

<table>
for ($loop = 1; $loop <=$numberOfRowsInTable ; $loop ++)
{?>
<tr>
<?php
if ($loop <= $numberOfRowsInCol1){?>
<td class="leftCell">
<?php echo $arrayCol1[$loop-1];
}
else
{?>
<td  class="noborder">
<?php } ?>
</td>

<?php
if ($loop <= $numberOfRowsInCol2){?>
<td class="leftCell">
<?php echo $arrayCol2[$loop-1];
}
else
{?>
<td  class="noborder">
<?php } ?>
</td>
    .....
<?php
if ($loop <= $numberOfRowsInCol5)
{?>
<td class="leftCell">
<?php echo $arrayCol5[$loop-1];
}
else
{?>
<td  class="noborder">
<?php } ?>
</td>
</tr>
 <?php } ?>
</table>
```

The problem is where there is no text to the left of a cell that has text the side has no border.

[image]

Comment: Try adding `border-left:1px solid #000 !important;` to `.leftCell{border: 1px solid black;}` and see if there is any change..

Comment: @vascowhite Interesting - does that include the class? The <td could be outside and the class inside? I have tried this with <td> outside but no joy.

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: @Lal yes - thank you. I tried that before but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: @Lal - I am not sure I can. It needs HTML2PDF. Does fiddle allow that?

Comment: oh i see..try to generate it as an html before converting it into pdf..we'll fix the errors first and then convert it into pdf.See if everything is correct in html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the css property `border-collapse: collapse;` on your table. And define your table like this :

```
<table cellspacing="0">
```

I had the same issue with the left border on my array. I suspect the left border doesn't works when you set `border-collapse: collapse;`. I found this workaround to fix that.